C - How to free a double void pointer that has an array of dynamic structs assigned to it with malloc
My C looks like this.
typedef struct thing
{
    void *fooStruct;
} thing;

typedef struct foo
{
    int *somethingNumber;
    char something;
} foo;

extern void **double_ptr;
void *ptr;

int main() {
    ptr = (struct thing*)malloc(sizeof(thing) * 5);
    double_ptr = &ptr;

    for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++) {
        ((struct thing *)*double_ptr)[i].fooStruct = (struct foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
    }

    // <Things I've tried to free the memory>

    return 0;
}

I've tried a few of things so I can free all of the memory I malloc'd throughout the program (all of the dynamic 'foo' structs, all of the dynamic 'thing' structs, 'ptr', and 'double_ptr'), but I keep running into errors. Tried searching here but I haven't found anything that has helped me.
Some of the attempts I remember so far:
// Attempt 1:
free(double_ptr);

// Attempt 2:
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    aux_ptr = &((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i]; 
    free(aux_ptr);
}

free(double_ptr);

// Attempt 3:
void *aux_ptr;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    aux_ptr = ((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i].fooStruct; 
    free(aux_ptr);
    aux_ptr = &((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i]; 
    free(aux_ptr);
}

free(*double_ptr);

// Attempt 4:
void *aux_ptr;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    aux_ptr = ((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i].fooStruct; 
    free(aux_ptr);
    aux_ptr = &((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i]; 
    free(aux_ptr);
}

free(double_ptr);

I expected to have no memory leaks (or for the code to compile and run at all), but these various attempts don't fully work. Attempt 1 and 4 don't even compile (invalid pointer), while Attempt 2 and 3 have memory leaks.
Pointers have always been an issue for me, so I'm sorry if the solution is easier than I think. I'd REALLY appreciate some help :c

First of all get rid of all the void * declarations in the structs so you can see what you're actually doing. You will need forward declarations of those structs, but you needn't expose the actual declarations of them to the caller, if that's your reason for using void *. And if it isn't your reason, there is no valid reason at all, so don't do it. Don't write code like this. You only confuse yourself. Please edit your code here accordingly..

Hi! Thanks for taking time to reply. I understand, however I'm only using void beacause I'm being asked to do so, I wish I didn't have to. (The code is a small snippet of a bigger college project, but this is the part I'm having issues with)

I still suggest you take them out so you (and we) can what's really happening. It will clarify the situation for you. Then put them back when it works, when you submit your assignment. Terrible assignment, and you can tell your prof. I said so.

It's been solved, but the post you liked kind of helps! It's similar to the answer that worked for me, but it wouldn't help me free the structs inside the structs

The linked Q&A (from 2018, and only one of myriad versions) demonstrates "first freeing each pointer stored in the array, then free the pointer to the array." You have to learn to "draw knowledge" from examples, then apply that knowledge to your particular problem.

PS: dynamic memory allocation CAN fail. Your code does not check the returned values from malloc(), but proceeds to use what could be NULL pointer(s)... A "good" answer should have highlighted this to you... C'est la vie, eh?

For each call to malloc, there should be a corresponding call to free.
Looking at the allocation code:
ptr = (struct thing*)malloc(sizeof(thing) * 5);
double_ptr = &ptr;

for (int i = 0; i<5 ; i++) {
    ((struct thing *)*double_ptr)[i].fooStruct = (struct foo*)malloc(sizeof(foo));
}

You have a single malloc for an array stored in ptr, then a single malloc in a loop run 5 times for the fooStruct member of a struct thing.  So you want to free exactly that in the reverse order.
Attempt 3 is the closest.  You're calling free twice in the loop, but you only called malloc once in the initial loop.  Specifically, &((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i] doesn't point to allocated memory, so get rid of that.
void *aux_ptr;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    aux_ptr = ((struct thing*)*double_ptr)[i].fooStruct; 
    free(aux_ptr);
}

free(*double_ptr);


Not incorrect, but gives the impression an extra pointer variable is needed. free( void *ptr ); makes this answer unnecessarily cluttered. (Increases the number of maintenance points in the code.)
